# PHP: I cannot retrieve ALL cookies, each set correctly within same domain

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting cookies on the first page. The coding of this may seem strange, but it is because browser reloads pages several times, I can't figure it out, and I had to generate the following to even get cookies to set how and when I want. This is working for me, in as much as it sets the cookies and redirects as I want:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['location'])) {
    if($_GET['pg'] !== 'Please Select Your Location') {
        $EntryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($EntryURL == '/') { $EntryURL = '/index.php?pg=Home'; 
    }

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['EntryURL'])) { setrawcookie('EntryURL', $EntryURL, '0', '/'); }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['location'])) { setcookie('location', 'TRANS', '0', '/'); }

    header($redirect); 

    }
}
```

This script jumps to a PHP processing page where more location cookies are set:

```
setcookie('lt', 'ct');
setcookie('ct', $rct);
setcookie('co', $rco);
setcookie('st', $rst);
setcookie('stl', $statelong);
$location = $rct . ' (' . $rco . '), ' . $rst;
setcookie('location', $location);

header($redirect);
```

However, I cannot recall the first two cookies at this step. If I continue to the third part (on third page), I can access all the cookies set in step/page 2, but not from page 1. If I manually check on my computer, all the cookies are there. If I `print_r($_COOKIE)` I only see cookies set from step/page 2, again verifying that all the cookies are actually set.

I have played with parameters, I have tried renaming the first two cookies, I just do not understand why I cannot have access to them as they exist.

I never move in and out of subdomains, all scripts and pages are within the root. I have tried manually refreshing, this does not help.

Ideas?

Comment: First of all, due to my lack of knowledge, 'serialize it to json' means NOTHING to me. lol.

Comment: I guess it would be proper to insert my cookie creation into two lines, the first two from the first page, and the next ones on the second page, which I will have to work on, but is that actually addressing my problem, because I feel like I will end up with the same problem, yet with more proper code. lol

Comment: @RyanVincent, thanks for answering me, btw... I'm not certain I know what you mean that I am using separate cookies as an array. I think that I agree that I should store the first two cookies with one `setcookie()` and the next few cookies in a second `setcookie()` and I will rewrite to make my code better. For the record, I do not need many other cookies, these should be all I am using, and I am not trying to do 'nasty things' haha. This is saving city name, county name, etc. But the first two cookies I cannot retrieve and I'm not sure saving them differently will help (it might?)

Comment: I have totally tried setting the EntryURL cookie as a session and I still cannot call it back.